# How to setup NGINX to deploy dynamic multiple Single Page Apps?

Tags: html, nginx

My Goal:

Using nginx as front-end server, and I have multiple HTMLs and Single Page Applications (as HTML file), other static files will be uploaded to CDN (like .js/.css/.img).

So, how can i set nginx config once, solve all dynamic SPAs?

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.com;
  rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
  root  /opt/vipkid/ngTest;
  expires -1;

  location / {
      try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ $uri =404;
  }

  location ~* ^/(?<single>.+)/.*$ {
      try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ $uri /$single/index.html =404;
  } 
}
```

Now I have files like this:

```
├── dira
│   ├── index.html
│   └── suba.html
├── dirb
│   └── index.html
└── index.html
```

using the config above, I can reach:

- Go example.com;  Render: /index.html    right
- Go example.com/dira;   Render: /dira/index.html   right
- Go example.com/dira/suba;     Render: /dira/suba.html   right
- Go example.com/dirb;    Render: /dirb/index.html   right
- Go example.com/dirb/single-route;    Render: /dirb/index.html  right
- ***Go example.com/dirb/single-route/sub;   Render: 404  wrong***

So, how to config ningx to solve this problem? Thanks~

Comment: Is `$single` supposed to be a single path element. You might try using a character class that excludes `/`, for example: `^/(?<single>[^/]+)/`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thx , it works